# Django Query string stay in url during session

Tags: python, django, url

I pass the Query string through a form like this:

```
<form action="stockChart" autocomplete="off" method="GET">
  <input type="text" required="required" name="Ticker" maxlength="5">
</form>
```

and then it redirects me to the page with all the data corresponding to the input and puts my input in the url /stockChart?Ticker=AAPL

```
views.py
     def stockChart(request):
         TICKER = request.GET['Ticker'].upper()
```

But if I go to another tab where I also want to use the same ticker it doesn't work, since the URL doesn't have the query string in it.
Right now I'm using TICKER = request.session['Ticker'] but by doing that the URL doesn't contain the query string. Is there a way to keep the string (?Ticker?AAPL) in the url, when navigating to other pages?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what "if I go to another tab" means.

By assuming you're accessing URL `/stockChart` in another tab and you want it to show your last input `Ticker`, you could do this in your view:

1. if `request.GET['Ticker']` has a value, save it to `request.session['Ticker']` and display page
2. if is missing `request.GET['Ticker']` and `request.session['Ticker']` has data, redirect to `'/stockChart?Ticker={}'.format(request.session['Ticker'])`